# Integrate PyQt with a sql orm library (sqlalchemy, peewee, etc.)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyqt5, peewee

PyQt has some nice features like QSqlTableModel and QSqlRelationalTableModel, however, it doesn't contain ORM functionalities and I hate using raw SQL statements in my program. What is a best way to integrate a SQL ORM library like Sqlalchemy, to PyQt SQL facilities? Currently the only solution I can think of is to build my object models in SqlAlchemy and execute the compiled SQL statements with QSqlDatabase manually. Is there any better way to do this? Are there any ways, say, to build a custom backend/adapter for SqlAlchemy that use QSqlDatabase? Other ORM libraries like Peewee are fine, too.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html?highlight=create_engine#sqlalchemy.create_engine

Create a fake engine using the 'mock' strategy that redirects all compiled sql statements to the QSqlDatabase to execute.

There seems to be a catch: functionalities that require interaction with a real database will not work, like checking if a table exists before creation. 
Also this doesn't seem to work with the Session API, any calls to `commit()` and `flush()` will cause a `NotImplementedError`.